# c++ struct in map as value - error "no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list"

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to use a struct as a value in a map. Why do i have to use the value_type to insert something into the map?

```
#include <map>

struct myStruct {};

int main()
{
    std::map<int,myStruct> myStructMap;
    myStruct t;

    myStructMap.insert(std::map<int,myStruct>::value_type(1, t));  // OK

    myStructMap.insert(1,t);
    // Error:
    //   "no instance of overloaded function 'std::map [...]' matches
    //    the argument list"
}
```

Comment: `struct` is a keyword. You shouldn't use it to name something.

Comment: i really would like to know why that received a vote down? i formated this question for several minutes, and the guy next to me, who programmed C++ for a few years also didn't know the reason...

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz: Then he should be fired immediately. What on earth is `myStructMap.insert(1,struct);` supposed to mean?! You're also missing a `;`. This is _not_ your testcase.

Comment: sorry, i just renamed it for stackoverflow, this was my minimal working example

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz: Well you renamed it wrong. That's why we expect you to post your testcase/SSCCE _verbatim_!

Comment: OK, post some real code without spurious mistakes, then we can try to compile it and see. For example, `struct myStruct{}` is missing a trailing `;`.

Comment: See [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) You're Welcome !

Comment: ok, sorry you guys! i will copypasta excactly the code that fails from now on!

Comment: I've downvoted because this question "does not show any research effort" whatsoever, and could easily be solved by taking a look at the documentation for `std::map`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Quite simply, there is no such function as `std::map::insert` that takes the key as one argument and the value as another.**

You are expected to `std::map::insert` with the actual value type of the map, which is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`.

Sure, the C++ standard library *could* have provided this overload for you, but it has no reason to.

The only function that does something similar to what you're trying to do, is the C++11 [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) (and `emplace_hint`):

```
myStructMap.emplace(1,t);
```

In this example, the arguments are directly *forwarded* to the constructor of `value_type`.

Comment: But a `value_type` typedefed as `pair<const key_type,mapped_type>`; oh  and maybe mention `emplace` ;)

Comment: I know, but I wrote it for the sake of completeness ;)

Comment: why does std::map<int,int> myMap; myMap.insert(1,1); work then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Am I right that it will result in a call to the range (iterator) signature?

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz: [It doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bad032f7db27ae0).

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz and LRiO: `myMap.insert(1,1);`  shouldn't compile.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: I thought I'd gotten it to a minute ago, but not sure now what I saw. This makes far more sense.

Comment: i give up, that was my worst stackoverflow wquestion by far, but thank you anyway. At least i know now where the problem was!

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz: Smack your colleague for me. :)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: It shouldn't compile, but there's no guarantee that it won't; for example, if there's a non-standard conversion from `int` to `const_iterator`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour in clang's c++ lib: `insert` is a template function: `template <class _InputIterator>
        void insert(_InputIterator __f, _InputIterator __l)`. It would work if  expression `*__l` would be valid.